Application fails to start with no dependencies found when executed from intellij
I have created what I think is a multi module project that uses micronaut and maven, however, the application fails to start when I try to run it using intelliJ. Note: If I manually build the project and then start the jar, everything works as expected.
If I just create the run config by specifying the main class and child module, the application will start, but if I call send a request to the endpoint that saves info in a database, it will tell me that the EntityManager bean doesn't exist. I have another module that handles all the database operations and such module has the dependencies that create the EntityManager.
If I go to Settings | Maven | Runner and click on Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven and then try to run the project, it will fail with something like this:
Failed to execute goal on project service: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.zane:service:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.zane:resources:jar:1.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.zane:resources:jar:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.zane:resources-service:pom:${revision} (absent): com.zane:resources-service:pom:${revision} was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. 

Find here each of the pom files I have created.
Parent pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.zane</groupId>
  <artifactId>resources-service</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>


  <parent>
    <groupId>io.micronaut.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
  </parent>

  <modules>
    <module>data-access</module>
    <module>resources</module>
    <module>service</module>
  </modules>


  <properties>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <jdk.version>21</jdk.version>
    <release.version>21</release.version>
    <micronaut.version>4.4.3</micronaut.version>
    <micronaut.runtime>netty</micronaut.runtime>
    <micronaut.aot.enabled>false</micronaut.aot.enabled>
    <micronaut.aot.packageName>com.zane.aot.generated</micronaut.aot.packageName>
    <revision>1.0.0</revision>
  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-netty</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-serde-jackson</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-http-client</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.test</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-test-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-data-tx-hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
      <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>micronaut-validation-processor</artifactId>
      <version>4.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
      <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <configFile>aot-${packaging}.properties</configFile>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.diffplug.spotless</groupId>
        <artifactId>spotless-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.43.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <java>
            <googleJavaFormat />
          </java>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <!-- Uncomment to enable incremental compilation -->
          <!-- <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation> -->

          <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-http-validation</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.core.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>io.micronaut.serde</groupId>
              <artifactId>micronaut-serde-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${micronaut.serialization.version}</version>
              <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                  <artifactId>micronaut-inject</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
            </path>
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.group=com.zane</arg>
            <arg>-Amicronaut.processing.module=resources-service</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>


service pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>service</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.zane</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources-service</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <exec.mainClass>com.zane.Application</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zane</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zane</groupId>
            <artifactId>data-access</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>java</executable>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                        <classpath/>
                        <argument>-noverify</argument>
                        <argument>-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argument>
                        <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote</argument>
                        <argument>${exec.mainClass}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

resources pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.zane</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources-service</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zane</groupId>
            <artifactId>data-access</artifactId>
            <version>${revision}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

data-access pom
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>data-access</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.zane</groupId>
        <artifactId>resources-service</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-hibernate-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-data-tx-hibernate</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-jdbc-hikari</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-validation-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

Why is IntelliJ failing to run the application and what do I need to change so I can start it?
Note: If I manually build the project and then start the jar, everything works as expected.
Thanks.

When you enable "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven" the build is performed entirely by Maven and it is a Maven error there. It looks like its failing to lookup your Parent Project and possibly also fails to resolve the value of ${revision}. Also, how exactly do you "manually build the project"?

hello @romanv-jb. Thanks for your reply.
Yep I agree, seems like it is ignoring the parent, specially because when I run it from intelliJ I see that it starts with the service module, where the main class is.
Also, by manually build I mean by running mvn clean package

How exactly do you run the Project with IDEA (it provides multiple options of doing so)? Also, check your Maven Local for any .lastUpdated files and try removing them. Would you be able to share your Project?
